# Find $P[X+Y\le 16]$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ have bivariate normal distribution with parameters $\mu _X=5$, $\mu _Y=10$, $\sigma^2_x=1$, and $\sigma^2_Y=25$. If $\rho=0$, find $P[X+Y\le 16]$

$P[X+Y\le 16]=\displaystyle\int_{}^{}\displaystyle\int_{x+y<16}^{}f_{x,y} (x,y) dx dy , $ then

$P[X\le 16 -Y]=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{16-y}f_{x,y} (x,y) dx dy $

Let $U= X + Y $ then $du=dx $
 and $u=(16-y)+ y = 16$

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{16}f_{x,y} (16-y,y) du dy$

Given that $p_{xy}= 0$ then $f_x(16-y)f_y(y) = f_{x,y} (16-y,y)$ they are independents

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{16}f_{x,y} (16-y,y) du dy= \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{16} f_x(16-y)f_y(y)du dy$

Who can I continue?

To solve this problem I shouldn't use (Moment-generating function , sum of normal is normal ,Characteristic function or someting like that )

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hint: $X+Y$ is a normal random variable, and you know its density function if you can find its mean and variance.  Can you figure out $E[X+Y]$ and $\sigma^2_{X+Y}$ from the given information? Once you have that, it is easy to compute $P(X+Y < 16)$ in terms of the cumulative standard normal distribution function $\Phi(x)$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate     Yes, is easy if you know that X+Y - N(15,26) but the problem is that I can use it

Comment: OK, before doing anything else, rotate the coordinates by $\pi/4$ so that the new random variables $(W,Z)$ have joint density that you can find (via Jacobians, etc) without necessarily needing to know that they are jointly normal and you serendipitiously discover $(W,Z)$ are also jointly normal (though not independent). But then $$P(X+Y\leq 16) = P(Z \leq \sqrt{128})$$ (because the line $x+y=16$ rotates to become horizontal and at height $\sqrt{128}$ above the axis) which is computable in terms of $\Phi(\cdot)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Your first step is all wrong.  $P\{X+Y\leq 16\}$ is *not* $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{16}f_{x,y} (16-y,y) dx dy$ as you have it, 
but is instead
$$P\{X+Y \leq 16\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{16-y}f_{X,Y} (x,y)\,
\mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{16-y}f_X(x)f_Y(y)\,
\mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy.$$

Calculating this directly is a tedious exercise in algebra, and it is much easier
if you break the problem into two parts: compute the density of $Z=X+Y$ and then find
$P\{Z \leq 16\}$.  The first is done via
$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy$$
where the integrand is of the form $Ae^{-Q(y; z)}$. *Complete the square* in the
exponent by writing $y^2 -2ay + b = (y-a)^2 + (b-a^2)$ so that the integral
is a "constant" times a normal density and thus its value is just this "constant",
which of course is an exponential function of $z^2$ that is readily recognized
as a normal density. All this, of course, simply *derives* the result
that you are not supposed to "use", *viz.* that $X+Y$ is a normal random
variable, but I think the prohibition is against simply *copying* the assertion
that the sum of independent normal random variables is normal from your book
and using it without proof.